# Uploading an app to AppStore from a different intunesconnect account

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an application that needs to be uploaded to the AppStore from a different itunesconnect account than my own. Will I be needing their distribution certificates while complying in Xcode so that they can upload the .app file or will mine do aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If the other itunesconnect account is of another company than **yes**.
- If it's of same your company and an member with admin level then **no**.

Comment: Yeah the account is of another company, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The iTunesConnect account is actually independent of your developer account used to build the app.

So you need two things to happen:

1. They make your existing Apple ID a *Team Member* so you can have provisioning profiles and get certificates to build and sign the app. Once they do this, every time you sign into the member center you will be prompted to pick a team and you will find XCode now has a choice of teams.
2. They create a **separate iTunes Connect** apple ID for you using a different email address from your current one. This needs to be a real address on which you can receive emails.

The second bit seems a bit weird but eventually made sense to me. There's a whole toolset which is based around you having a unique login to iTunesConnect where the Apple ID you use to login to iTunesConnect implies the team. It's not just a case of them being able to change a single website.

I am a member of three teams - my original app dev company, my startup touchgr.am and a client team. I use that main apple ID as my iTunesConnect ID for my original work and had to get people to add two more apple IDs for iTunesConnect.